# How do I get the name attribute of a hidden element within a div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a nested grid with is inside a 'div' element. I have a hidden element to determine if the div is expanded or not. I need to get the name of the hidden element (uniqueID) to set it. The jquery to open/close the grid is below:

```
function DivExpandCollapse(RecipientID) {
        var div = document.getElementById(RecipientID);
        var img = document.getElementById('img' + RecipientID);
        var hiddenID = //div + ?? to ID the hidden element
        var hiddenElement = document.getElementById(?????);

        if (div.style.display == "none") {
            div.style.display = "inline";
            img.src = "Images/minus.png";
            //Setting the hidden element to 'expanded'
            hiddenElement.val("1");
        }
        else {
            div.style.display = "none";
            img.src = "Images/plus.png";
           //Use ID of hidden element to set to 'hide'
           hiddenElement.val("");
        }
    }
```

The div ID is defined in the markup:

```
<tr><td colspan="100%">                  
 <div id="div<%# Eval("RecipientID") %>" style="display:none"> 
     <asp:HiddenField ID="recdevgvIsExpanded" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
 </div>       
 </td></tr>
```

Comment: Is the `RecipientID` in the function and the `Eval()` same? Then you can use `'div#'+RecipientID`

Comment: I don't get it. You're not making it clear what exactly you try to achieve, what you have tried so far, and why it didn't work.

Comment: As a side note, `.val()` isn't a function on DOM elements.

Comment: Yes.  RecipientID is the same as Eval.  So the div element ID is div2886 for example. I need the ID of the hidden element, using the div element

Comment: I am showing/hiding a nested grid. The 'div' contains a grid that is hidden when initially displayed. When a user opens the grid and pages to the next set of values within the grid, the nested grid closes.  I need the hidden element to keep track of which grids are open. In the code behind, It sets the hidden values using its uniqueID. I learned that in jquery, the attribute is the **name**.  If I can get the ID of the hidden element for the specfic grid, I can set it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use attribute selector in jquery

https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

your jquery selector will be like:

```
$('[style="display:none"]')
```

but if there is any inline styles with the display it will not select the element

Comment: That does not work.  I believe because it is part of a nested grid.  The 'div' contains a grid that is hidden when initially displayed. When a user opens the grid and pages to the next set of values within the grid, the nested grid closes.  I need the hidden element to keep track of which grids are open. In the code behind, It sets the hidden values using its uniqueID. I learned that in jquery, the attribute is the name.  If I can get the ID of the hidden element for the specfic grid, I can set it.

Comment: I would like to use the **div** element because it is unique and available in the function.

Comment: Wouldn't that ID the div element?  I need the hidden element from the div element.

Answer (score 0):

"I need the hidden element to keep track of which grids are open". Perhaps you can try this:

1. Add an additional CssClass in your `<asp>`
2. Filter it using jQuery

```js
$('.getThisID').click(function() {
  
  var elem = $(this).find('.getMyID');
  var id = $(elem).attr('id');
  
  console.log(id); // Tadaaa, your ID here

  // Then you can style $(this), either to display:inline, or create an additional img and set the img src
});
```

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="100%">                  
    <div id="div_<%# Eval("RecipientID") %>" class="getThisID" style="display:none"> 
      <asp:HiddenField ID="recdevgvIsExpanded" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="getMyID"/>
    </div>       
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The showing and hiding actions are working.  The problem is when the user pages within an open Grid.  Paging to the next page in the nested grid causes the grid to close on postback.  I need the ID of the hidden element when the DivExpandCollapse function is called.

Comment: No.  I need the ID of the **HiddenField**. The Id, **recdevgvIsExpanded** is not the complete UniqueId because it is part of a nested grid.  How to get the HiddenField using the div Id because it is a child of the div element.

Answer (score 0):

Without using jQuery you can do this:

```
var hiddenElement = document.getElementById(RecipientID).getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

Asp:HiddenField renders as a

```
inputp[type=hiudden]
```